# Wireshark capture communication between devices on specified IP addresses

Tags: wireshark

Using wire shark, how can capture or filter communication between two devices on a larger network. Eg, say we have this system:

```
PC1 ----|
        |
        |    ______
PC2 ----|---|      |--- Special Device
        |   |Router|
        |   |______|
PC3 ----|
```

If i want the packets of communication between `PC1` (`ip 139.136.59.13`) and the `Special device` (`ip 139.136.59.14`). What is the filter command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can use filters such as

```
(ip.src == 139.136.59.13 && ip.dst == 139.136.59.14) || 
(ip.dst == 139.136.59.13 && ip.src == 139.136.59.14)
```

This is complex. Better is to use `ip.addr` which will match on either `src` or `dst`:

```
(ip.addr == 139.136.59.13 && ip.addr == 139.136.59.14)
```